# Phonegap 2.7.0 won't build

Tags: cordova

I have tried several ideas found online but it seems that `phonegap 2.7.0` just wont build for Blackberry.

I followed the phonegap getting started guide, all seems fine except for two things.

`$ /path/to/my_new_cordova_project/cordova/build <platform>` would not build and

Ripple will not work:

Error message from ripple:

```
GET cordova_plugins.json 404 (Not Found) ripple.js:50
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < cordova-2.7.0.js:10884
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova-2.7.0.js:10718
Channel not fired: onNativeReady cordova-2.7.0.js:10711
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady cordova-2.7.0.js:10711
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady cordova-2.7.0.js:10711
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually thrown when there is a "<" inside of some Javascript. Check how the files are included in the index.html and check if there is a spare "<" lying around someplace.